# Cloning object via reflection with special constraints

Tags: c#, reflection

suppose an object with this properties

```
public int? Prop1 { get; set; }
public string Prop2 { get; set; }
public EntityCollection<X> Prop3 { get; set; }
public EntityCollection<Y> Prop4 { get; set; }
public EntityCollection<Z> Prop5 { get; set; }
```

i can copy `prop1` and `prop2` with this method:

```
    public static void SetProperties(PropertyInfo[] fromFields,
                                             object fromRecord,
                                             object toRecord)
    {
        PropertyInfo fromField;

        if (fromFields == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (PropertyInfo t in fromFields)
        {
            fromField = t;

            fromField.SetValue(toRecord,
                               fromField.GetValue(fromRecord, null),
                               null);
        }
    }
```

but i don't know **how copy each of `prop3` , `prop4` and `prop5` to another object**!

**Edit:**
i should **not** `Serialize` object! I do this work because my object has big data and with this trick i can copy some data.

it is funny to say if i say original source of this problem! i use `EF` as `ORM` and use data objects in a `Silverlight` clients via `WCF`. When i send `List<Foo>` in `WCF` , it sends `List<Foo>` and its relationships data!! and clients died!

Comment: Your point about not using serialize is lost on me; if you want to clone a large graph ("big data"), you will have 2 * a large graph - the serialization in the middle seems moot.

Comment: @Marc Gravell:just copy a property with EntityCollection<> type via reflection.

Comment: right; so either you want a deep clone (in which case Serialize should work, and you're going to have twice the data), or you want a copy of the entity collection (so just call `SetValue`) - it is still not clear to me where lies the problem.

Comment: how to reflect properties with EntityCollection<> Type

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is make the objects `Serializable`. You can then Serialize the object in Memory and deserialize it as a new Cloned object.

I have these two functions:

```
    public static MemoryStream ToMemoryStream(object entity)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        formatter.Serialize(ms, entity);
        return ms;
    }

    public static T FromMemoryStream<T>(Stream stream)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        stream.Position = 0;
        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
```

With your Class like this

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass 
{
    public int? Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public EntityCollection<X> Prop3 { get; set; }
    public EntityCollection<Y> Prop4 { get; set; }
    public EntityCollection<Z> Prop5 { get; set; }
}
```

you can now serialize the class to Memory and Create a clone from that.

```
public MyClass Clone()
{
    var myclass = new MyClass();
    /* Do Some init */

    var ms = ToMemoryStream(myclass);

    var myNewObject = FromMemoryStream<MyClass>(ms);
    return myNewObject;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that X,Y and Z should also be `Serializable` in this example.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace following line

```
  fromField.SetValue(toRecord, 
                           fromField.GetValue(fromRecord, null), 
                           null);
```

With these statements,

```
        if (typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(t.PropertyType))
        {
            IList fromList = fromField.GetValue(fromRecord, null);
            IList toList = fromField.GetValue(toRecord, null);
            foreach (var item in fromList)
                toList.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            fromField.SetValue(toRecord,
                               fromField.GetValue(fromRecord, null),
                               null);
        }
```

You have to replace IList to some suitable interface probably ICollection or something else that will work with EntityCollection, I didnt have anything to test so I just posted this example.